# I am currently sitting in a plane on the runway that has been delayed for three hours. Do I get free food?

Tags: air-travel, eu, passenger-rights

This is an internal EU flight. EU law states that the airline has to provide food and drink for flights delayed more than 2 hours, however it is unclear how this takes place if the plane is on the runway before it is delayed for the full two hours. Ie: the plane was delayed 90 minutes before boarding, then sat ready to take off for a further hour with everyone on board, then returned to the stand.
Am I entitled to anything? I'm pretty hungry.

Comment: Probably yes, but either way they can't serve food until you are up at cruising altitude.

Comment: Cheers. We're taking off now so I guess I'll find out in a bit!

Comment: Rule #1 of travel - "Always have snack!"

Comment: Did you get free food?

Comment: @Doc I thought it was “always carry a towel” /s

Comment: @RoboKaren If I recall correctly, the protocol for being hungry involved sucking on a corner of the towel.  Personally, I'd rather carry some snacks...

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful advice. The flight ended up arriving 3 hours late. The initial delay was caused by the airline and this lengthened due to weather, I'm hoping that I'm still elligible for compensation in this case. We never did get anything to eat, but I got a McDonald's when we landed so all is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by boarding the plane, legally speaking, your flight started.

It is likely that you will arrive late. So possibly you will qualify for some amenities at your destination.

NB: There are reports that some airlines might by full purpose have passengers board knowing well that the flight will depart at all or not within a reasonable amount of time, so they will have to unboard passengers again without ever leaving. But as this breaks the 2 hours / three hours rule, no compensation, at least not in terms of meals and the like.